# Amazon S3 Multipart UploadPartRequest allows only single thread to upload at the same time using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload video files Amazon S3 using Multipart upload method in asp.net and I traced the upload progress using logs. It uploads 106496 each time and runs only single thread at a time. I did not notice that multiple threads running. Please clarify me on this why it is running single thread and it's taking long time to upload even for 20Mb file it's taking almost 2 minutes.

Here is my code, which uses `UploadPartRequest`.

```
private void UploadFileOnAmazon(string subUrl, string filename, Stream audioStream, string extension)
    {
        client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

        // List to store upload part responses.
        List<UploadPartResponse> uploadResponses = new List<UploadPartResponse>();


        // 1. Initialize.
        InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initiateRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = subUrl + filename
        };

        InitiateMultipartUploadResponse initResponse =
            client.InitiateMultipartUpload(initiateRequest);

        // 2. Upload Parts.
        //long contentLength = new FileInfo(filePath).Length;
        long contentLength = audioStream.Length;
        long partSize = 5 * (long)Math.Pow(2, 20); // 5 MB


        try
        {
            long filePosition = 0;
            for (int i = 1; filePosition < contentLength; i++)
            {

                UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = subUrl + filename,
                    UploadId = initResponse.UploadId,
                    PartNumber = i,
                    PartSize = partSize,
                    FilePosition = filePosition,
                    InputStream = audioStream
                    //FilePath = filePath
                };

                // Upload part and add response to our list.
                uploadRequest.StreamTransferProgress += new EventHandler<StreamTransferProgressArgs>(UploadPartProgressEventCallback);                 
                uploadResponses.Add(client.UploadPart(uploadRequest));

                filePosition += partSize;
            }

            logger.Info("Done");


            // Step 3: complete.
            CompleteMultipartUploadRequest completeRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = subUrl + filename,
                UploadId = initResponse.UploadId,
                //PartETags = new List<PartETag>(uploadResponses)

            };
            completeRequest.AddPartETags(uploadResponses);
            CompleteMultipartUploadResponse completeUploadResponse =
                client.CompleteMultipartUpload(completeRequest);

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred: {0}", exception.Message);
            AbortMultipartUploadRequest abortMPURequest = new AbortMultipartUploadRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = subUrl + filename,
                UploadId = initResponse.UploadId
            };
            client.AbortMultipartUpload(abortMPURequest);
        }
    }
    public static void UploadPartProgressEventCallback(object sender, StreamTransferProgressArgs e)
    {
        // Process event. 
        logger.DebugFormat("{0}/{1}", e.TransferredBytes, e.TotalBytes);
    }
```

Is there anything wrong with my code or how to make threads run simultaneously to speed up upload?

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem - the single-thread doesn't bother me, but the 106496 bytes cap is totally weird.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than managing the Multipart Upload yourself, try using the `TransferUtility` that does all the hard work for you!

See: [Using the High-Level .NET API for Multipart Upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileDotNet.html)

Comment: Indeed, `TransferUtility` is convenient in most cases. There are corner cases where the programmer may want to implement something that may interfere in the way the transfer happens (for example, support band limit), then it will become a "problem" - (s)he might extend `FileStream` and limit there, but it doesn't guarantee the SDK implementation won't queue disk IO - IIRC, currently it does not, so this solution should work, but it's quite hacky. Again, this is a very corner case - normally will be just fine using `TransferUtility`.

Comment: Multi-part supports pause/resume functionality. but by using transferUtility API. we cannot make use of pause/resume. The question is How to achieve single thread into multi-thread for parallel uploading to get faster uploads.

Answer (score 0):

The `AmazonS3Client` internally uses an `AmazonS3Config` instance to know the buffer size used for transfers ([ref 1](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/f5c9bce1d6303036718e1b0ad09fe481dd1b52c9/sdk/src/Services/S3/Generated/_bcl35/AmazonS3Client.cs#L58)). This `AmazonS3Config` ([ref 2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/f5c9bce1d6303036718e1b0ad09fe481dd1b52c9/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/ClientConfig.cs#L54)) has a property named `BufferSize` whose default value is retrieved from a constant in `AWSSDKUtils` ([ref 3](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/f5c9bce1d6303036718e1b0ad09fe481dd1b52c9/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Util/AWSSDKUtils.cs#L50)) - which in the current SDK version defaults to 8192 bytes - quite small value IMHO.

You may use a custom instance of `AmazonS3Config` with an arbitrary `BufferSize` value. To build an `AmazonS3Client` instance that respects your custom configs, you have to pass the custom config to the client constructor. Example:

```
// Create credentials.
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
// Create custom config.
AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config
{
    RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1,
    BufferSize = 512 * 1024, // 512 KiB
};
// Pass credentials + custom config to the client.
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, config);

// They uploaded happily ever after.
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense... We need to upload parallely. how to achieve it by doing it in multi-thread.

Comment: @SantoshKokatnur: You have to adjust `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`. The default is 2, iirc.

Comment: Where can we assign ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit ?

Comment: Anytime before you start your file transfers.

Comment: Nope, Its again uploading slowly... :(

Comment: I am doing it in windows form application. Not in web application.

Comment: Besides the `DefaultConnectionLimit`, did you try using the instructions I wrote on my answer as well? If that does not work, I suggest you to post an actual question here or on the official AWS forums.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134382/discussion-between-santosh-kokatnur-and-jweyrich).

Comment: @jwerich Could you please chat privately. have some doubts regarding this topic.